# Remove Service Worker that loads whole website from cache

Tags: javascript, caching, subdomain, service-worker, browser-cache

I developed a new website for a customer, that had previous website running on the same domain. I deployed the site and found out that www. subdomain still shows the previous website, which I later (after some headache ) found out was because the previous website registered a service worker that was loading the whole website from cache (except some dynamic json data).

Now my question is... how the hell you solve this deadlock.
I can unregister the worker manually from my local browser, of course. But how to do this for a random user, that visited the site before deployment. When such user accesses the www. subdom, it doesn't even touch my server. Accessing the site via bare 2nd level domain works fine, but it is not like I can change the worker for subdoms from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not neccessarily a general/easy method... but...

First order of business should be trying to replace the SW with your own, that does nothing. Just find out the url that SW was served from and place an empty file at that location.

That might not work, though, because the SW registration code can be hidden behind some "source changed?" check, which was my case.

So second order of business, in that case, is tricking the code into thinking that something changed and it should reload. In my case, I have identified `app-data.json`, which contained `webpackCompilationHash`. So after serving a fake file with random hash, the browser finally registred my dummy SW and the website loaded correctly on the next refresh.